# How can I properly count with For loop in python, odoo?

Tags: python, for-loop, odoo

There are book records with different genres, and this function counts only one of those. How can I make it count all genres?

The function:

```
@api.multi
def _total_count(self):

    for genre in self:
        if genre.name:
            count_num = 0
            ids = self.env['books.books'].search([('genre_ids', '=', genre.name)])
            if ids:
                count_num += 1
                genre.count = count_num
```

Comment: Do you want to count every book of every genre or do you want to count the genre number ?

Comment: Hi @guest user, may be `collections.Counter` for each genre helps? Please, provide input data an example of desired output

Comment: @MikhailStepanov i want to count all the books with the same ganre. For example there are 5 books with genre Drama and 3 books with genre Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a compute field `count` in `gender model` and you want
To set its value automatically whenever you add a book to this gender
you can do something like this:

1. First I'm assuming that `gender_ids` is many2many field in your book 
   let us assume that is defined like this:

```py
           gender_ids = fields.Many2many(co_model='gender.model.name',
                                         relation='book_gender_rel',
                                         column1='book_id',
                                         column2='gender_id')
```

2. so you need to create the same `many2many` field in your gender
   , I mean the field should have the same fields names and the same relation name
   only with small changes in the values of `column1 and column2` like this:

```py
       book_ids = fields.Many2many(co_model='book.book',
                                   relation='book_gender_rel',
                                   column1='gender_id',
                                   column2='book_id')
```

3. make your `count` field a compute field like this, it's better to add
   `store=True` if the computing is heavy, and you do not want to take
   a lot of time just to show genders records in a view (specialy Tree view).

```py
       # I renamed the field just to be more readable for others.
       count_book = fields.Integer(string='Number of books',
                                   compute='count_number_of_books',
                                   store=True,
                                   help='Contains number of book that belong to this gender')


       @api.depends('book_ids')
       def count_number_of_books(self):
           """ Count number of books that belong to this gender."""
           for gender in self:
               gender.count_book = len(gender.book_ids)
```

And this way you can use `count_book` in your reports or anywhere else without
having to worry about computing it because Odoo will take care of it.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late... thank you for the solution it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the results somewhere. Here is how to do it with a Python dictionary, by name of the genre:

```
def _total_count(self):
    total_per_genre = {}
    for genre in self:
        if genre.name:
            count_num = 0
            ids = self.env['books.books'].search([('genre_ids', '=', genre.name)])
            if ids:
                count_num += 1
                genre.count = count_num
            total_per_genre[genre.name] = len(list(ids))
     print(total_per_genre)
     return total_per_genre
```

Edit: I misread the question. I think `len(ids)` is what you need (I used `len(list(ids))` because I'm not sure about the type of `ids`. Note that I do not know odoo.